# How to search for unanswered, open questions questions with at least 1 close flag?

Tags: support

I wanted to search for questions which have been flagged to be closed but not in my review queue which are open as yet and don't have upvoted answers.

Searching for `closed:0 answered:0` gives me all(flagged as well as unflagged; there doesn't seem be a thing called flagged in search); how do I search them?

Comment: Start here http://data.stackexchange.com/askubuntu/query/201327/pending-close-votes-flags

Comment: @Braiam: What is the `FlagTypeId` there? Any guide for doing executing such a query?

Comment: All paths leads [this way](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2677/213575)